# Beginner - Naive Bayes Classification runs into Error - Record Problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, valueerror, naivebayes

for our project work in university we need to write a machine learning code. Unfortunately I don't have any programming knowledge and am a bit helpless.
My classification is Naive Bayes and when I run the code I get an error:
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Unfortunately, I can't do anything with this and also nothing with the solutions found so far in the forum. Maybe someone can help me?

```
dat = pd.get_dummies(df)

# Define X and y
X = dat.drop('RESP', axis = 1)
y = dat['RESP']

# training and testing data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# assign test data size 30%
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(X,y,test_size= 0.3, random_state=0)

#BERNOULLI
# importing classifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB

# initializaing the NB
classifer = BernoulliNB()

# training the model
classifer.fit(X_train, y_train)

# testing the model
y_pred = classifer.predict(X_test)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-22-df3c037d90d0> in <module>
     23 
     24 # testing the model
---> 25 y_pred = classifer.predict(X_test)

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in predict(self, X)
     80         """
     81         check_is_fitted(self)
---> 82         X = self._check_X(X)
     83         jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
     84         return self.classes_[np.argmax(jll, axis=1)]

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in _check_X(self, X)
   1145     def _check_X(self, X):
   1146         """Validate X, used only in predict* methods."""
-> 1147         X = super()._check_X(X)
   1148         if self.binarize is not None:
   1149             X = binarize(X, threshold=self.binarize)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in _check_X(self, X)
    517     def _check_X(self, X):
    518         """Validate X, used only in predict* methods."""
--> 519         return self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse="csr", reset=False)
    520 
    521     def _check_X_y(self, X, y, reset=True):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    564             raise ValueError("Validation should be done on X, y or both.")
    565         elif not no_val_X and no_val_y:
--> 566             X = check_array(X, **check_params)
    567             out = X
    568         elif no_val_X and not no_val_y:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    798 
    799         if force_all_finite:
--> 800             _assert_all_finite(array, allow_nan=force_all_finite == "allow-nan")
    801 
    802     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
    112         ):
    113             type_err = "infinity" if allow_nan else "NaN, infinity"
--> 114             raise ValueError(
    115                 msg_err.format(
    116                     type_err, msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```